# Redmine lock inactive users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, rake-task, rakefile

I'm trying to create a rake file which will be linked to crontab, and will have the ability to lock users which are inactive for 90 days in the group ID 600, but something is not correct in the file.
this is the lock_inactive_users.rake

```
namespace :redmine do
  desc "Lock inactive users" 
  task lock_inactive_users: :environment do
    inactive_users = User.joins(:groups)
                         .where('groups.id = ?', 600)
                         .where(type: 'User')
                         .where('last_login_on < ?', 90.days.ago)

    inactive_users.find_each(batch_size: 500) do |user|
      user.update(status: User::STATUS_LOCKED)
      puts "User #{user.login} (ID: #{user.id}) has been locked." 
    end
  end
end
```

while executing the file Im ending with error
bundle exec rake redmine:lock_inactive_users RAILS_ENV=production

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "groups"
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve in coding terms but the error is telling you that here is no table called groups so the `User.joins(:groups)` will never work